# Rspec and Carrierwave. When changing config.storage to file for testing, I get an ArgumentError is not a recognized storage provider exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, carrierwave

I have two carrierwave uploaders in my application. ImageUploader is for uploading locally and ImageRemoteUploader for uploading to Amazon S3 storage using fog. ImageUploader has storage set to `:file` and ImageRemoteUploader has storage set to `:fog`. This setup works fine, but when I start to set up my rspec tests, things change.

The problem arises when I change the ImageRemoteUploader to use `:file` storage during testing. I do this in my fog initialization file. The file, 
*/config/initializers/fog.rb*, looks like:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  if Rails.env.test?
    config.storage = :file
    config.enable_processing = false
  else
    config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',       # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'XXXXXXXX',       # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'XXXXXX',       # required
    :region                 => 'XXXX'  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
    }
    config.fog_directory  = 'xxx'                     # required
    config.fog_public     = true                                   
  end 
end
```

When I do this, I get an `ArgumentError is not a recognized storage provider` carrierwave exception. When I use the fog credentials (I don't set config.storage to :file), the test works as expected.

Carrierwave 0.7.1, Rails 3.2.8, Ruby 1.9.3, Rspec 2.10

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try moving the `config.storage` and `config.enable_processing` lines into `lib/initializers/carrierwave.rb`, as recommended in the [Carrierwave docs](http://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave).

`Fog` also has its own mocking support, which is enabled by running `Fog.mock!` before the examples. This might be a better approach.

Comment: I move the `config.storage`, `config.enable_processing` along with the `Rails.env.test?` if statement out of the fog.rb and into its own carrierwave initializer and put that into the Carrierwave.config do block. I think this is what you meant. In this case, tests run, but test files are uploaded to the S3 repository. 

I'll look into Fog.mock!